# R Shiny Reative Codependant Inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create a Shiny Dashboard that will filter a data frame based on several different inputs. I am trying to get the options for the inputs to update based on the selection of other inputs. Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do with the `cars`data.

I've played around with both using `uiOutput` and `updateSelectInput` but neither has worked. I don't understand when one should be used over the other.

I have also tried using them in combination with `switch()`, but again I don't fully understand when it should or should not be used.

There is probably an easier way to set this up and in reality, I have 3 different `selectInput`s that I would want to update.

## Code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)


# Load Data
data("mtcars")

mtcars = mtcars %>%
        mutate(am = factor(am),
               cyl = factor(cyl),
               gear = factor(gear))

# Generate options
Cly_opts = c("Dont Filter By Cly", unique(mtcars$cly))
Gear_opts = c("Dont Filter By Gear", unique(mtcars$gear))

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
        dashboardSidebar(

                uiOutput("Stdy_in"),
                
                uiOutput("Gear_in")
                
        ),
        
        dashboardBody(

                fluidRow(
                        plotOutput("plot1")
                )
        )
)



# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
   
        Gear_lst <- reactive({
                if(input$Cyl_in != "Dont Filter By Cyl"){
                        # Get Gears
                        gear_lst = mtcars %>%
                                filter(cyl == input$Cyl_in) %>%
                                select(gear)
                        
                        return(gear_lst$gear)
                        
                }else{
                        # Get Gears
                        gear_lst = mtcars %>%
                                select(gear)
                        
                        return(gear_lst$gear)
                }
        })
        
        output$Gear_in <- renderUI({
                selectInput(inputId = "Gear_in", 
                            label = "Gear Number",
                            choices = Gear_lst())
        })
        
        
        Cyl_lst <- reactive({
                if(input$Gear_in != "Dont Filter By Gear"){
                        # Get Cly
                        cyl_lst = mtcars %>%
                                filter(gear == input$Gear_in) %>%
                                select(cyl)
                        
                        return(cyl_lst$cyl)
                        
                }else{
                        # Get Cly
                        cyl_lst = mtcars %>%
                                select(cyl)
                        
                        return(cyl_lst$cyl)
                }
        })
        
        output$Gear_in <- renderUI({
                selectInput(inputId = "Gear_in", 
                            label = "Gear Number",
                            choices = Cyl_lst())
        })
        
        
        # Plot
   output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
           # Create data frame based on filters
           if(input$Cyl_in == "Dont Filter By Cyl" & input$Gear_in == "Dont Filter By Gear"){
                   p_data = mtcars %>%
                           select(am, mpg) %>%
                           gather(key = am, value = mpg)
           }
           
           
           if(input$Cyl_in != "Dont Filter By Cyl" & input$Gear_in == "Dont Filter By Gear"){
                   p_data = mtcars %>%
                           filter(gear == input$Gear_in) %>%
                           select(am, mpg) %>%
                           gather(key = am, value = mpg)
           }
           
           
           if(input$Cyl_in == "Dont Filter By Cyl" & input$Gear_in != "Dont Filter By Gear"){
                   p_data = mtcars %>%
                           filter(cyl == input$Cyl_in) %>%
                           select(am, mpg) %>%
                           gather(key = am, value = mpg)
           }
           
           
           if(input$Cyl_in != "Dont Filter By Cyl" & input$Gear_in != "Dont Filter By Gear"){
                   p_data = mtcars %>%
                           filter(gear == input$Gear_in) %>%
                           filter(cyl == input$Cyl_in) %>%
                           select(am, mpg) %>%
                           gather(key = am, value = mpg)
           }
           
           
           p = ggplot(p_data, aes(x = factor(am), y = mpg)) +
                   geom_boxplot() + 
                   theme_classic()
           
           print(p)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: there is `updateSelectInput()` so use that instead of creating it with `renderUI`. I expect you to deal with infinte looping too as one is codependant on another and it will cause an issue

Comment: Yes, thank you, in this case, the infinite loop is an issue. But why `updateSelectInput()` vs. `renderUI`? I've seen it both ways. Is `renderUI` for more general cases and `updateSelectInput()` just more specific to this use case?